# Java Web App will not start in Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, web, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy a Java Web App in Cloud Foundry. It fails to Start. When I deploy it Locally , It Starts. It also starts and works when I explode the war locally and upload the entire tomcat directory as a Java Standalone app. I see from the Logs that its started, But the Status is unknown when doing the vmc apps command. I get a 404 when accessing the URL.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a small example that demonstrates your problem? We call this an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) around here.

Comment: If you could also post the logs content from CloudFoundry.com too, that would be of great help.

Comment: Dan, I can send you the war file. here are the final lines of the log file  *Oct 28, 2012 4:17:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/delements-0-f5a0dfb708696c74962bc14ad3592825/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/log4j-cfvideodemo.xml]
Oct 28, 2012 4:17:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext*

Comment: have you checked if  you are binding the required services like databases to your service on pcf?